# Can't click a certain button in Celerity + Jruby

Tags: jruby, celerity

Oh masters of screen scraping. I'm using jruby and Celerity (both newest versions), and I CANNOT figure out how to click this button. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="chart-toolbar noprint" style="float: left;">
<ul>
<li>
</li>
<li>
<span class="btn-export icon-24 download-24" title="Export"></span>
```

I've tried everything, I cannot get it to click. Here is my current code:

```
browser.button(:class, "btn-export icon-24 download-24").click
```

Here is the error:

> Celerity::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate Button, using :class and "btn-export icon-24 download-24"
>                 assert_exists at /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.9.1/lib/celerity/element.rb:179
>     assert_exists_and_enabled at /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.9.1/lib/celerity/clickable_element.rb:69
>                         click at /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/celerity-0.9.1/lib/celerity/clickable_element.rb:9
>                        (root) at ./test.rb:17

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
browser.button(:class, "btn-export icon-24 download-24").click
```

try

```
browser.span(:class, "btn-export icon-24 download-24").click
```

hope this helps!!